# Format painter feature in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I wish to know if there is any short cut in LaTeX to suffix and prefix `$` symbol for math text. Say I have to write many times some variables such as `x`, `y`, and `z`. I wish to type them normally, and at the end, I just wish that if I select, say `x`, two `$` symbols are automatically inserted (before and after `x`). We find "Format painter" feature in Word. I wish to know if there is one such in LaTeX too.

Comment: This is really something done at the editor level, not by LaTeX itself. Which editor do you use?

Comment: I use Texshop...

Comment: In an editor such as Sublime Text you can create multiple selections and put the settings such that typing `$` places the selection between dollar signs. That would probably be a little off topic for this site though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would suggest with TeXShop. For the case where there are *numerous* replacements to be done, this will actually be faster than manually selecting each `x` and replacing this).

1. Set `x` as the search target: Either through the `Find` panel, or selecting a single `x` and hitting <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>.
2. Put `$x$` in the PASTE command via <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

Then hitting <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> will find the next occurrence of `x`. Then:

1. If this is not something you want to replace <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> will leave this alone and take you to the next occurrence of `x`.
2. If this is a math `x` then <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> will replace this with `$x$` and take you to the next occurrence of `x`.

### Notes:

- For Windows replace <kbd>⌘</kbd> with <kbd>CNTL</kbd>.